# How do I avoid an "Unobserved Task" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, task

I've gotten myself into a mess with tasks, and I'm not sure of a good way to get out of it.

I have data I'm going to asynchronously fetch from two different APIs. The connection is dubious, and I have a tight time constraint on how long I can wait. The desired behavior is "I want to wait up to 2 seconds to get both sets of data, if 2 seconds expires I'll take any that have completed, even if that's nothing."

I pulled this off with a sort of janky setup like this: (It already runs on a worker thread, so the synchronous waits aren't a problem.)

```
Task<IData> firstTask = _firstDataSource.GetDataAsync()
Task<IData> secondTask = _secondDataSource.GetDataAsync()

var whenBothTasksFinish = Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);

var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

Task.WhenAny(whenBothTasksFinish, timeoutTask).Wait()

bool timedOut = timeoutTask.IsCompleted

if (timedOut) {
    return newIData[0];
}

var sources = new List<IData>();
if (firstTask.IsCompleted && !firstTask.IsFaulted) {
    sources.Add(firstTask.Result);
} else if (firstTask.IsFaulted) {
    LogException(firstTask.Exception);
}

// Same block as above for secondTask
```

It's messy, but I was cramped for time when I wrote it. Maybe there's a better way to go about it, that's going to be on my mind tonight. Right now I'm confused as to how to fix this one.

**The problem** happens when network connectivity is turned off, both of my IData tasks fail. Since I log their exceptions, I satisfy the conditions that would otherwise lead to UnobservedTaskException. But their exceptions also bubble into the Task.WhenAll() and, presumably, the Task.WhenAny(). That eventually gets finalized and my app throws UnobservedTaskException. Oddly enough, that doesn't seem to consistently crash the app, but it does *sometimes* which is why I'm concerned.

I've looked around and it seems like one way I could deal with this is a fairly simple continuation:

```
whenBothTasksFinish.ContinueWith(t => LogException(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

The only reason I'm not just doing that is I like how the current structure lets me provide a more individualized log message: I care about which task threw the exception. I don't want to log the messy AggregateException I get, but haven't looked too much into unraveling it.

It's late and I haven't spent a lot of time rethinking this algorithm. Is there either a way to make sure I acknowledge the task exceptions or a way to restructure this to get the results I want without involving so many moving parts?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of different things, and arrived at this solution:

```
  whenBothTasksFinish.ContinueWith((parent) => {
    var flattened = parent.Exception.Flatten();
    flattened.Handle((ex) => true);
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

In normal circumstances, this would be a bad idea. It's the equivalent of an empty `try/catch`. But in my scenario, I'm going to handle each exception separately later. This makes the framework quit complaining that I haven't handled the exceptions from the `WhenAll(`).

Oddity: when I debug in Xamarin Studio, holding a breakpoint for too long can sometimes cause the `WhenAll()` task to get collected before that continuation has run. I could probably deal with that via `GC.KeepAlive()` but meh.

Answer (score 0):

I had something very similar and a similar solution, just leaving this here in case anyone is dealing entirely with asynchronous code.

When I tried making a minimum reproducible code snippet, this is what it boiled down to:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

async Task ThrowsAsync() => throw new Exception();
Task DoesNotThrowAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;

// set a manual reset event when an unobserved task exception occurs
var mre = new ManualResetEventSlim();
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (_, __) => mre.Set();

// minimum reproduced code
async Task StrangeBehaviorAsync() {
    var throwTask = ThrowsAsync();
    var noThrowTask = DoesNotThrowAsync();
    var whenAll = Task.WhenAll(throwTask, noThrowTask);

    // --- Some irrelevant code that befuddled the situation ---

    await throwTask;    // Naively just awaiting the task I cared about.  Causes unobserved task exception and exits the while loop below
    // await whenAll;   // No unobserved task exception, so while loop never exits
}


try
{
    await StrangeBehaviorAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

// wait for unobserved task exception
while (!mre.IsSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No unobserved task exception...");   
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Running this in a .NET interactive notebook, the above code will exit when `whenAll` is finalized which causes the unobserved task exception to be thrown.  Uncommenting the `await whenAll` "observes" the exception and prevents the reset event from being set, and the while loop runs forever.

So just like your example, I was awaiting the inner task but there was this other "WhenAll" task that was not being awaited (or in your case, "continued"), so the framework treats it as unobserved.