# How do I introduce a time out handler for this Connect Async sub in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

I want to write a code which connects to a Server, but times out after 10 seconds. I thought of Task.WhenAny() would do the trick. So far, I have come with the following code:

```
    private async Task<bool> tryConnect() //Times out after 10 seconds
    {
        bool connected = false;
        bool alreadyWentOut = false;
        await Task.WhenAny(
            Task.Run(async() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (alreadyWentOut) await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
                }
            }),
            Task.Delay(10000)
        );
        alreadyWentOut = true;
        return connected;
    }
```

Is there a smell in the current code? In my IDE (using jetbrains rider) it is giving me the following warning

[image]

If there is a code small, how do implement this better?

Comment: Is `CrossInAppBilling` your own code?

Comment: No it's a library

Comment: Do you have a link to it?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes it's https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin

Comment: @Enigmativity However, I want to make it general. I don't want to have to modify the other library

Comment: Yes, understood. However, the parts of the library you've shown us make it really hard to do what you want. I want to see if the library offers any other connection methods.

Comment: Having looked at the code it does look like it only has the API you're looking at. You do appear to have a race condition. You can't always be sure that the connection hasn't been opened. I'd need to look further at the source to see what that might mean, but it's nearly midnight here. I'm off to bed.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are trying to do is to attach a `DisconnectAsync` continuation, after the `ConnectAsync` has timed-out and has become a fire-and-forget task. Here is an explicit way to do it, that uses the new (.NET 6) [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) API:

```
private async Task<bool> TryConnect(int timeoutSeconds = 10)
{
    var connectTask = CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();
    try
    {
        return await connectTask.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        _ = DisconnectAfterConnectAsync(); // Fire and forget
        return false;
    }

    async Task DisconnectAfterConnectAsync()
    {
        await connectTask;
        await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
    }
}
```

My instinct says that you'll find more problems down the route, related with the ambient `CrossInAppBilling.Current` property, and with subsequent attempts to `TryConnect` while a fire-and-forget `DisconnectAfterConnectAsync` is still in-flight. [Fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778423/fire-and-forget-using-task-run-or-just-calling-an-async-method-without-await) is a recipe for problems.

Comment: Understood, how bout if I add an exception handler within the fire and forget? That would tie things up. There is nothing I can do, the actual timeout set by the Library (which essentially connects to the Google Play/AppStore) is very long. I can't expect the user to wait.

Comment: @user1034912 adding error handling inside the leaked task will help for logging a possible error, and for nothing else. The chaos that is expected to occur if you try to `TryConnect` again after a recent failed attempt, is not easy to solve.

Comment: You are right. I guess the only was is to redesign the page, so it doesn't lock the user when google play/apple appstore is unavailable (E.g. when the user have a bad internet connection). It times out when google/apple play store times out.

Comment: @user1034912 does the `ConnectAsync` API supports configuring the connection timeout?

Comment: No it doesn't. Also the respective AppStores controls the time outs.

Comment: @user1034912 one idea would be to use a single connect attempt multiple times. If the `ConnectAsync` does not complete in time, you could keep a reference to the `Task` and `await` it again later, instead of invoking the `ConnectAsync` a second time. I don't know the details of your API, so this idea might not be feasible.