# Does order in asynchronous execution matter?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm learning asynchronous programming in C# and I'm puzzled at this finding. The way I have come to understand the paradigm is: The function being `await`ed leaves a callback that gets executed when the flow of execution has ended. This allows the main thread to execute the following lines of code. Based on this, wouldn't these two examples (methods are implemented as naive Task.Delay() to mimic stalling):

```cs
Task task_teeth = brushTeethAsync();
Task task_shoes = wearShoesAsync();

await task_teeth;
await task_shoes;
```

and

```cs
Task task_teeth = brushTeethAsync();
await task_teeth;

Task task_shoes = wearShoesAsync();
await task_shoes;
```

have the same output. After all both give the stream of execution to other parts of the program when they're finished. Yet when I execute them, the first example runs as an asynchronous example would, while the second example runs sequentially waiting for the brush task to finish so wear task can resume.

I get that the second example defeats the purpose of being asynchronous but why?

```cs
    public static async Task brushTeethAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Brushing your teeth!");
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished brushing teeth");
    }

    public static async Task wearShoesAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Putting on shoes!");
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished wearing the shoes");
    }
```

Comment: When you are awaiting a Task it doesnt mean that the program continues to execute and it goes to the next line of code. Awaiting means that while waiting for the TaskA to finish dont hang up on the main thread but go and perform other system operations. When the TaskA is finished then you start and await for TaskB.

Answer (score 4):

> I get that the second example defeats the purpose of being asynchronous.

It doesn't. The purpose of being asynchronous is fulfilled, meaning that no thread is needlessly blocked. You might confuse the terms *asynchronous* and *concurrent*. In case the purpose was concurrency, yes, it would be defeated. Although async/await can facilitate concurrency, it's not its main purpose. The main purpose of async/await is to simplify writing asynchronous code, i.e. code that makes efficient use of threads.

Regarding the terminology, you might find this question interesting: [What is the difference between concurrency, parallelism and asynchronous methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods) I like [rahulaga-msft's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods/53838885#53838885) answer the most.

As a side note, whenever you launch multiple concurrent asynchronous operations, make sure to await all of them with [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall):

```
await Task.WhenAll(task_teeth, task_shoes);
```

Otherwise, if you await them one after the other and the first task fails, the second task will become a fire-and-forget task, which is [rarely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778423/fire-and-forget-using-task-run-or-just-calling-an-async-method-without-await/60781121#60781121) [advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316504/proper-way-to-start-and-async-fire-and-forget-call/61320933#61320933).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I tended to think of being asynchronous as parallel in a thread (if that makes any sense). So theoretically if there was both a GUI and our function executing for the time duration of 10 sec, without async would that mean that the GUI would freeze?

Comment: Good answer, as an addition, i would say that this fork-join solution might suffer from so called "straggler problem".  What if i wanna handle completion of every task, and do it asap and in a graceful manner? Stephen Toub once wrote a good article about it 11 years ago.

Comment: @XHOxha yes, blocking the UI thread for 10 sec would make the GUI non-responsive. You can prevent freezing reliably by using the `Task.Run`, that offloads all work to the `ThreadPool`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await/58306020#58306020 "await Task.Run vs await") answer for an explanation and examples.

Comment: @Ryan you might be referring to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/ "Processing tasks as they complete") or [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-sequences-of-asynchronous-operations-with-tasks/ "Processing Sequences of Asynchronous Operations with Tasks"). These are a bit advanced scenarios.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Yep, i am about first link.